# why does super function exactly use in my code?

Tags: django

My problem is about why exactly was super(CommentManager, self) used in 
 code below. couldn't that instance object in filter_by_instance just be used instead?

```py
class CommentManager(Models.Manager):
    def filter_by_instance(self, instance):
       content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
       obj_id = instance.id
       qs = super(CommentManager, self).filter(content_type=content_type, 
                                         object_id=obj_id).filter(parent=None)
       return qs
```

Couldn't it be something like this:

```py
class CommentManager(Models.Manager):
    def filter_by_instance(self, instance):
       content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
       obj_id = instance.id
       qs = instance.filter(content_type=content_type, 
                                         object_id=obj_id).filter(parent=None)
       return qs
```

Comment: What happened when you tried using that?

Answer (score 0):

When you override a method and run `super().method()` you're making sure the parent method will run. In your case it seems you're creating a method that it'll call the parent class method `filter` so instead of using `Model.objects.filter()` you can use `Model.objects.filter_by_instance()` and that will run the `.filter()` behind the scenes.